# Redirect page to new URL without losing SEO

Tags: http, redirect

slightly confused about all of these redirect codes.  So I have a website that has been live on

> https://domainA.com/subfolder

I have recently duplicated the site, but need to move it to a new domain

> https://domainB.com/subfolder

However, if people still visit the first domain, I need them to be redirected to the new domain.  However, I do not want to lose the SEO I have on the original domain.

I have seen that I could do a 301 or 303 redirect, although not sure what my best option is?  At the moment, within .htaccess I have added

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://domainA.com/subfolder/[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://domainA.com/subfolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainB.com/subfolder/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

This does not seem to do anything at the moment though.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfolder(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domainB.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]
```

This should work please report feedback

Regarding your question. Google advices 301 redirects so I think that is better keep it that way

---

### Different subfoder

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfolder(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domainB.com/DifferentSubFodler [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Say the new domain has a different name subfolder, would your solution change?

Comment: @kate_hudson yes, but if you change that subfolder name, that subfolder you must have it under your web directory aswell

Comment: Both of these domains are set up as an Alias.

Comment: @kate_hudson just edited my answer in case you want to point to another subfolder

Comment: In the second solution if you go to domainB.com/subfolder you will also be redirected to domainB.com/DifferentSubFodler is that what you're looking?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better work on Apache configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-available/your-site.conf